# PhoneGap Device Ready fires when device is not ready

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am seeing some bizarre behavior from PhoneGap. OnDeviceReady will fire, yet when I go to use the "device" variable, it is still undefined. I found some code that spoke to this and said use setTimeout to wait one second (again, after it says its ready) to actually use the variable (below):

```
setTimeout(function () {
    MobileDevice = new MobiDevice(device);
}, 1000);
```

This seemed to work initially, but now it looks like the time is indeterminate. I recently had to up the timeout to 5000. This is our current code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("starting setup");
    try {
            MobileDevice = new MobiDevice(device);

        console.log("created MobiDevice from a real device");
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("no device reference - mocking device");
        var d = {
            platform: "Android",
            version: 5
        };

        MobileDevice = new MobiDevice(d);
    }

    console.log("device setup complete");
}, 5000);
```

If it is indeed the case that the time is indeterminate, what are some strategies others have used to get around this. If it should not be indeterminate, where are areas I can look for fixes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What platform and version of PhoneGap as this sounds like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer here is two fold. One, PhoneGap being what it is, you have to wait for the device variable to be initialized even after the PhoneGap thinks the device is ready. I used setInterval and waited until I could use 'device' before passing it to my wrapper.

The other piece of this was the web. During our testing we wanted to be able to mock the device and forgo device initialization, cause it wasnt going to happen.

```
if (navigator.platform.match(/(mac|win)/i)) {
        console.log("on a browser, mocking the device");
        // we are on the browser
        // you can manually set properties here to test for different devices
        var d = {
            platform: "Android",
            version: 5
        };

        MobileDevice = new MobiDevice(d);
    }
    else {
```

Right now, we only care about iPhone and Android, thus if we just the navigator.platform, we can get what platform the browser is running on. This will be different between Windows, iPhone, Android, and Mac. Different enough that we can differentiate. If we ever decide to support WP then well have to change this, most likely

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use polling.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    if(device !== undefined)
        MobileDevice = new MobiDevice(device);
    else
        setTimeout( arguments.callee, 1000 );
}, 1000);
```

If you wish, you may temper with the timeout limit (here, 1000ms) such that it decreases after every call...you get the point.

Comment: Yeah, we are trying that now with setInterval until we have it. The question now is, when do we give up and assume we are on a browser. Checking the navigator JS object

Comment: frankly i've never worked with phonegap or on mobile devices...so i don't have much idea about navigator on mobile devices...if you can tell me how to differentiate then i might be able to help ya